Find all positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^4-21a^2b^2+4b^4$ is a divisor of $3^3\cdot7^2\cdot19$

Find all positive integers $a$ and $b$ so that $a^4-21a^2b^2+4b^4$ is a divisor of $25137$.

I am stuck with this math problem. I know that:
$$a^4-21a^2b^2+4b^4=(a^2+2b^2-5ab)(a^2+2b^2+5ab)$$
and
$$25137=3^3\cdot7^2\cdot19$$
but then I don't know how to continue. Could you please help?

Welcome to Math SE. Note that if $d = \gcd(a^2+2b^2-5ab,a^2+2b^2+5ab)$, then $d$ divides the difference of the factors, i.e., $d\mid 10ab$.

The comment of @JohnOmielan represents an elegant refinement that I would not have thought of.  My (inelegant) approach would be to let the factors be represented by $~F_1,F_2,~$ and attempt to apply the following analysis to each of $~F_1,F_2.~$ Use a $~\pmod{n}~$ argument, where $~n \in {3, 3^2, 3^3, 7, 7^2, 19},~$ to try to identify all ordered pairs $~(a,b) ~: ~a,b \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ such that $~F_1~$ and/or $~F_2~$ is congruent to $~0, \pmod{n}.~$

Re last comment, notice that you can easily find (for example) all quadratic residues $~\pmod{19},~$ by simply examining the set $~{0^2, 1^2, \cdots, 9^2}.~$ Note that (for example) $~(r + 19k)^2 \equiv r^2 \pmod{19},~$ and that $~(19-r)^2 \equiv (-r)^2 \equiv (r)^2 \pmod{19}.$

one cannot use the 3 or the 7. These are not quadratic residues $\pmod{17}.$  If the polynomial is divisible by $3$   then both $a,b$   are divisible by 3, and the quartic is divisible by $81.$   Same comment for $7$ and $2401$

Meanwhile, now emphasizing $a,b > 0$  we can only allow $a^2 - 5ab + 2 b^2 = 1$   and $a^2 + 5ab + 2 b^2 = 19.$   However, this requires $10ab = 18$  which is impossible in integers, see the comment by @JohnOmielan . So that's it, no positive solutions, likely the only solution is $a = \pm 1, b=0$

@WillJagy FYI, note that $a=1$ and $b=2$ gives $a^2+2b^2-5ab=1+8-10=-1$ and $a^2+2b^2-5ab=1+8+10=19$, so their product of $-19$ divides $25137$ and, thus, $(1,2)$ is a positive integer solution.

Isn't this question now settled? By Will's reasoning, we must have $a^2+2b^2\pm5ab\in S:={\pm1,\pm19}$. By John's observation the difference of the two factors is $10ab$. The only occasion when the difference of two numbers from the set $S$ is a multiple of $10$ is (observing that $a^2+2b^2+5ab>3$): $a^2+2b^2-5ab=-1$, $a^2+2b^2+5ab=19$. Hence $10ab=20$, and...

$a^2+5ab+2b^2=(1/4)(4a^2+20ab+8b^2)=(1/4)(2a+5b)^2-17b^2)$ might be helpful.

@JohnOmielan  I see what you mean, I mentally discarded negative divisors  unless they would both be negative.  Can't win 'em all.

@JyrkiLahtonen As neither $p=3$ or $p=7$ may be factors of $a$ or $b$, note that for both of these values of $p$ we have $a^4-21a^2b^2+4b^4\equiv (a^2)^2+(2b^2)^2\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has no solutions as the quadratic residues of $p=3$ is just $1$, while for $p=7$ they are just $1$, $2$ and $4$, with neither one having a sum congruent to $0$. Although the general protocol for community wiki posts is that most members are allowed to edit & update them, I'm unsure if that's appropriate for your answer. As such, you may wish to update it yourself with this if you think it's useful.

You are welcome to edit the CW answer @JohnOmielan. And fix my English ;-)

@JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for your feedback. As you suggested, I've edited the CW answer to include the details of my comment to you. However, as for "fix my English", I didn't find any problems with it, apart from an almost trivial issue of where I thought there should be an additional comma, so I didn't make any other changes.

@JohnOmielan  about possible English errors, Jyrki got his Ph.D. at Notre Dame in Indiana

Compiling an answer from the comments under main.

As stated later by John Omielan, neither $p = 3$ or $p = 7$ may be factors of $a$ or $b$, as then $p^4$ would be a factor of the quartic, which is not possible. Note also that for both of these values of $p$, we have $a^4 - 21a^{2}b^{2} + 4b^4 \equiv (a^2)^2 + (2b^2)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ has no solutions as the quadratic residues of $p = 3$ is just $1$, while for $p = 7$ they are just $1$, $2$ and $4$, with neither one having a sum congruent to $0$.
As explained by Will Jagy, either of the factors $a^2+2b^2\pm5ab$ is divisible by $3$ only when $3\mid a$ as well as $3\mid b$. But this would imply that the quartic is a multiple of $3^4$, which is a contradiction. If you are reluctant to do a brute force check, this also follows from the fact that $3$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $17$ (Gerry Myerson's comment also explains where the modulus $17$ comes from).
The same applies to divisibility by $7$. Again, the quartic can be divisible by $7$ only when both $a$ and $b$ are, but then the quartic would be divisible by $7^4$.
So the factors $a^2+2b^2\pm5ab$ must both belong to the set $$S=\{\pm1,\pm19\}.$$
When constrained to have $a,b>0$, it follows that $a^2+2b^2+5ab\ge8$. As the difference of the two factors is $10ab$ (first observed by John Omielan), we are forced to conclude that $10ab=20$
(or $10ab=0$, again violating the positivity assumption).
It follows that the only solution is $a=1,b=2$, and this checks out (another comment by John Omielan).


More generally for below, where primes $,p_i\mid 4-n^2\Rightarrow p\equiv 3\pmod{!4},,$ and $,e_i < 4$
$$q\prod_i p_i^{e_i} = a^4 + (4!-!n^2)ab+4b^4 =(a^2!+!2b^2-nab)(a^2!+!2b^2+nab)\qquad$$  by completing the square yields a difference of squares.

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that
$$a^4-21a^2b^2+4b^4\mid3^3\cdot7^2\cdot19.\tag{1}$$
Note that for $p\in\{3,7\}$ we have $p\equiv3\pmod{4}$ and so if
$$a^4-21a^2b^2+4b^4\equiv(a^2)^2+(2b^2)^2\equiv0\pmod{p},$$
then $a^2\equiv2b^2\equiv0\pmod{p}$, and hence $a\equiv b\equiv0\pmod{p}$. Then also
$$a^4-21a^2b^2+4b^4\equiv0\pmod{p^4},$$
contradicting the divisibility assumption in $(1)$. It follows that
$$a^4-21a^2b^2+4b^4\mid19.$$
We can factor the left hand side as
$$a^4-21a^2b^2+4b^4=(a^2+5ab+2b^2)(a^2-5ab+2b^2),$$
into a product of two factors that differ by $10ab$, a multiple of $10$. Then the product equals $\pm19$ and so $ab=2$, because $a$ and $b$ are positive. Then a quick check of the two remaining options shows that $(a,b)=(1,2)$ is the unique solution.

This seems to be the same as the solution sketched in the comments yesterday (summarized in Jyrki's answer). Why repeat it (without attribution)?
